# Angular Bootstrap: How to Allow 2 different date format

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to allow **MM/dd/YYYY** or **M/d/YYYY**.

Or this pattern:

- `02/04/1998`
- `02/4/1998`
- `2/04/1998`
- `2/4/1998`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Angular UI Bootstrap [datepicker documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker), the directive uses the date filter built into angular core ([documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)).

Based on the formatting you desire, you want `MM` for `format-month` attribute and `dd` for the `format-day` attribute.

Comment: when you put MM for month and dd for day, it won't accept 2/4/1998 as an input. It requires 02/04/1998.

Comment: what type of input field are you using?  you should be using `<input type="date" ... />

Comment: it is current type="text"

Comment: Hmmmm.  Ok.  Not all browsers support `<input type="date">` so we'll need to investigate this further.  Ironically, someone opened an issue on this same thing a few days ago.  I've just reopened it and added comments on what we need.  [Here's](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4496) the link.  Please feel free to help out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Seems that the issue has been fixed with this [commit](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/b1cfc5762dd80d8eecec95385a4dcf335cdb8ecd). You can now define a day/month/year-date in format `d!.M!.yyyy`. It allows an optional leading zero for day and month. See this [github-issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4496) for more information.

Available as NPM (angular-ui-bootstrap) from  V1.0.

Comment: Just used some `uib-datepicker-popup="{{'M!/d!/yyyy'}}"` myself. Thanks!